# Checking if integer exists in a variable geometric sequence

Tags: sql, t-sql, math, clr, sequences

I have the following requirement (to be developed in t-sql or in a crunch - a CLR).

I need to check if a given number (`X`) exists in a numeric sequence where the numeric sequence is variable based on a starting number (`Y`) and a multiplier (`Z`).

Take the following example:

```
Y = 5
Z = 2 (known as the 'common ratio' in the math-world i think)
```

Sequence would be, `5, 10, 20, 40, 80` & so on

I then need to check if `X` exists in the given sequence.

Problem is, `X`, `Y` & `Z` are completely variable.

What would be the mathematical formula for testing `X` against sequence based on `Y` & `Z`?

I'll be writing this in T-SQL, but feel free to post the answer in any language & i'll adapt accordingly.

I'm currently reading this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression to try and figure it out but thought i'd ask on here incase anyone has already done it / knows the solution.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a pure SQL solution would be

```
with anchor as (
  select @y as num
),
progression as (
  select num from anchor

  union all

  select num * @z from progression where num * @z <= @x
)
select case when exists (select 0 from progression where num = @x) then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 4):

Your sequence is created by evaluating

```
x = y*z^i
```

for i = 0,1,2,3,...

You can solve this for `i` as

```
i = Log[x/y]/Log[z]
```

being careful to avoid taking `Log[0]` and to accept only answers in which i is an integer, or since this is worked in floating-point numbers, acceptably close to being an integer.  If `i` is an integer (within the tolerance you establish) then your `x` is at that position within the series.